# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup and inserting into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pymysql

Im working on a project that involves web scraping, putting the data that was extracted into a database, then displaying the information on a webpage.I am doing everything on an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. For this my group is using BeautifulSoup to extract the data which works fine but when I get to inserting the data into a MySQL table i get the error that the

> table does not exist

I am using **pymysql** to insert the data. Any help would be much appreciated thank you my code is : 
The commented out part at the end works fine for printing out the information i need.

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql

# Connection to database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                 user='root',
                 password='ITSE1359',
                 db='SCHOOLS',
                 charset='latin1',
                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,3)]

for page in pages:

  response = get('https://www.campusexplorer.com/colleges/public-universities-in-texas/?schooltype=1%7C2%7C3%7C4&instate_tuition=1%3B5&four_year_schooltype=1&state=TX&city_or_zip=&distance=50&major=&page=' + page)

  html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

  school_names = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'media')
  school_city = html_soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'school-location')
  school_programs= html_soup.find_all('p', class_ = 'truncate-4lines')
  school_rating= html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'school-listing-data') 
  school_tuition=html_soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'green')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
          for x in range(len(school_names)):
               name = (school_names[x].text.rstrip(', TX'))


               sql = "INSERT INTO `school_tbl`(`name`) VALUES (%s)"
               cursor.execute(sql, (name))
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
     # print(school_city[x].text.rstrip(', TX'))
     # print(school_programs[x].text.split(';')[1])
     # print(school_rating[x].p.b.text)
     # print(school_tuition[x].text)
```

Comment: Well does the table exist?

Comment: Have you created the table?

Comment: You need to create table school_tbl with all columns that you created  in mysql using cli or some mysql client once you create it will work .

Comment: I check back on mysql and go under my SCHOOLS db which contains the table school_tbl with a column name and when i try to add the data using the script above i get the error "table SCHOOLS.school_tbl does not exist"